# Convert a SQL output from string to boolean

Tags: c#, boolean, tostring

I have a problems with data types in Visual Studio. I want to check if the value is equal to 1 but I'm getting an error.

I've attempted to use `ToString()` and was wondering if there was a way to use `ToBoolean()`.

```
string VerifyPasswordQuery = 
       "IF EXISTS (SELECT Password FROM UserData        
                   WHERE Password LIKE '" + TxtBoxLoginPassword.Text + "' 
                     AND UserName LIKE '" +  TxtBoxLoginUsername.Text + "')
        BEGIN SELECT 1 END";

SqlCommand VerifyPasswordCommand = new SqlCommand(VerifyPasswordQuery, Connection);
// maybe ToString(); ?
Boolean Password = VerifyPasswordCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToBoolean(); 

if (Password = 1)
```

My error is

> Error CS1061
>   'object' does not contain a definition for 'ToBoolean' and no accessible extension method 'ToBoolean' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What is the error? Generally your check for equality should read `Password == 1`, but since it's a boolean just `if(Password)` would be the correct syntax.

Comment: The syntax is wrong as i don't know how to use ToBoolean(). Not sure whether to do ToString() and then convert underneath.

Comment: ExecuteScalar returns an object, which does not implement the method ToBoolean - you could try Convert.ToBoolean(object) instead e.g. `Convert.ToBoolean(VerifyPasswordCommand.ExecuteScalar());`

Comment: @MikNiller Thanks dude, Boolean Password = Convert.ToBoolean(VerifyPasswordCommand.ExecuteScalar()); worked for me ;)

Comment: your welcome, happy coding

Comment: @Fusiozii of course you don't have passwords with a single quote inside of them. And perhaps you should look around to understand what happens when code is vulnerable to Sql Injections like your code above